# Aggregate data from consecutive time intervals

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get data every two days and then aggregate the data together, since it's so time-consuming to retrieve all the past day's data at once.

What I used is UNION ALL. Any alternatives that can tune this operation (without UNION ALL)?

For example:

Instead of getting past 7 days data with one query:

```
SELECT /*+ full(t) PARALLEL(t,10) */ TRUNC(DATE) AS CREATE_DATE, NAME1, NAME2, TYPE, STATUS, COUNT(1) AS COUNT, ID 
FROM table 
WHERE REQ_DTM < SYSDATE + 1 AND DTM > SYSDATE - 6 
    AND (STATUS != 'DONE') 
    AND (TEST_MODE is null or TEST_MODE ='N') 
GROUP BY ID, NAME1, NAME2, TYPE, TRUNC(DATE), STATUS 
ORDER BY ID, NAME1, NAME2, TYPE, STATUS, TRUNC(DATE) DESC;
```

Get data every 2 days, then use UNION ALL:

```
SELECT TRUNC(DATE) AS CREATE_DATE, NAME1, NAME2, TYPE, STATUS, COUNT(1) AS COUNT, ID 
FROM (SELECT /*+ full(t) PARALLEL(t,10) */ 
        DATE, NAME1, NAME2, TYPE, STATUS, ID 
        FROM table 
        WHERE _DTM < SYSDATE + 1 AND DTM >= SYSDATE - 1
            AND (STATUS != 'DONE')
            AND (TEST_MODE is null or TEST_MODE ='N') 
        UNION ALL
      SELECT /*+ full(t) PARALLEL(t,10) */ 
        DATE, NAME1, NAME2, TYPE, STATUS, ID 
        FROM table 
        WHERE DTM < SYSDATE - 1 AND DTM >= SYSDATE - 3
            AND (STATUS != 'DONE') 
            AND (TEST_MODE is null or TEST_MODE ='N') 
        UNION ALL
      SELECT /*+ full(t) PARALLEL(t,10) */ 
        DATE, NAME1, NAME2, TYPE, STATUS, ID 
        FROM table 
        WHERE DTM < SYSDATE -3 AND DTM >= SYSDATE - 5
            AND (STATUS != 'DONE')
            AND (TEST_MODE is null or TEST_MODE ='N') 
        UNION ALL
      SELECT /*+ full(t) PARALLEL(t,10) */ 
        DATE, NAME1, NAME2, TYPE, STATUS, ID 
        FROM table
        WHERE DTM < SYSDATE - 5 AND DTM > SYSDATE - 6
            AND (STATUS != 'DONE') 
            AND (TEST_MODE is null or TEST_MODE ='N'))
GROUP BY ID, NAME1, NAME2, TYPE, TRUNC(DATE), STATUS 
ORDER BY ID, NAME1, NAME2, TYPE, STATUS, TRUNC(DATE) DESC;
```

Comment: Looks like an XY problem. What are you trying to achieve by such transformation? It's pointless to repeat the same query with union for each date instead of filter on date range

Answer (score 0):

Please check below to serve the purpose.

```
WITH Q AS(SELECT l, d1 dd1, replace(d2, 7, 6) dd2 
    FROM (select level l, 
           (-1*(level))+2 d1,
           (-1*(level)) d2
    from dual a connect by level <= 8)
    where mod(l, 2) = 1)
SELECT TRUNC(DATE) AS CREATE_DATE, NAME1, NAME2, TYPE, STATUS, COUNT(1) AS COUNT, ID 
    FROM (
    SELECT /*+ full(t) PARALLEL(t,10) */ 
            DATE, NAME1, NAME2, TYPE, STATUS, ID 
            FROM table, Q
            WHERE DTM < SYSDATE + Q.dd1 AND DTM >= SYSDATE + Q.dd2
                AND (STATUS != 'DONE')
                AND (TEST_MODE is null or TEST_MODE ='N') 
    )
    GROUP BY ID, NAME1, NAME2, TYPE, TRUNC(DATE), STATUS 
    ORDER BY ID, NAME1, NAME2, TYPE, STATUS, TRUNC(DATE) DESC;
```

I have generated date deduction numbers using the below and injected the same in the main query. You can tweak below for desired results in case of any deviations in a number of days.

```
SELECT l, d1 dd1, replace(d2, 7, 6) dd2 
FROM (select level l, 
       (-1*(level))+2 d1,
       (-1*(level)) d2
from dual a connect by level <= 8)
where mod(l, 2) = 1
```